# How to add a custom search engine in chromium 68.0.3440.75 in contextual menu like Opera?

Tags: chromium, search-engines

I try to add custom search engines like Opera does, by right clicking on a custom search box : 'add custom search box'.

Is there any way with chromium 68.0.3440.75 ?

And how to use it without any search box like Firefox or Opera ? Or there's an addon to have a real search box

(I think it's a shortcut like `foobar%`)

Comment: Open the search engine page you want to add in one tab. Then open this settings page in 2nd tab `chrome://settings/searchEngines`. You can ADD button to add the search engine.

Comment: I don't see any add button anywhere. If I need to go to settings->search engines each time I need to switch, it's a PITA. How can I query an added search engine ? IIRC, there's a %foobar trick